# scaling standardized or weighting

Tags: r, cumsum

I hope I can find answer for this question here.  I have this piece of code that I am trying to analyze closely,

```
alphas <- matrix(runif(900), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
z <- t(apply(alphas, 1, cumsum)) 

for(i in 1:nrow(z)){
  z[i, ] <- z[i, ] / (1:ncol(z))
}
```

I am trying to understand what does `z[i,]<- z[i,]/(1:ncol(z))` code is doing for the matrix alphas. I know we are dividing each column by the sequence of columns in the input matrix. I also know when using apply with margin 2, we apply the function we are interested in, which is in this case "cumsum" over the rows of matrix alphas. Thats basically what I know, I have no clue why the next line and what does to my matrix alphas?

I would appreciate some insigts
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code I would say you are calculating **row-wise cumulative means** of your `alphas`.

With the line in your loop you're doing a vector division that yields the averages of cumulative sums of each column.

Look what `ncol(z)` yields

```
> ncol(z)
[1] 3
```

So basically what you're doing with `z[i, ] / (1:ncol(z))` in your loop is a division of each row by a vector, or sequence respectively, with length of column numbers, i.e. `c(1, 2, 3)` or just `1:3`.

Consider the first row of your `alphas` and your `z`.

```
set.seed(42)  # for sake of reproducibility

alphas <- matrix(runif(900), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
z <- t(apply(alphas, 1, cumsum)) 

> alphas[1, ]
[1] 0.9148060 0.9370754 0.2861395

> z[1, ]
[1] 0.914806 1.851881 2.138021

> cbind(alphas[1, 1], mean(c(alphas[1, 1:2])), mean(c(alphas[1, 1:3])))
         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.914806 0.9259407 0.7126737
```

The core of your loop yields

```
> z[1, ] / 1:ncol(z)
[1] 0.9148060 0.9259407 0.7126737
```

So each element of a row of `z[1, ]` will be divided by its corresponding divisor of the vector, yielding the means of the aggregated cells of 
Your loop simply does this for your whole `z` matrix.

Apropos—faster and more convenient in *R* we do this in a vectorized way within a function. Since you understand `apply()` you will understand `sapply()`. Which we will use by first defining a function.

```
FUN1 <- function(i){
  z[i, ] / 1:ncol(z)
}

M <- t(sapply(1:nrow(z), FUN1))

> head(M, 3)
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.9148060 0.9259407 0.7126737
[2,] 0.8304476 0.7360966 0.6637630
[3,] 0.7365883 0.4356275 0.5094157
```

This yields the same as your loop but in the *R* way.

In one step we can do this saying

```
z <- t(sapply(seq_len(nrow(alphas)), 
              function(i) cumsum(alphas[i, ]) / seq_along(alphas[i, ])))

> head(z, 3)
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.9148060 0.9259407 0.7126737
[2,] 0.8304476 0.7360966 0.6637630
[3,] 0.7365883 0.4356275 0.5094157
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much for such a clear and elegant explanation.  I am still trying to figure out why we do this for of calculation to matrix alpha? Is it for scaling, for example? I guess I want to say that I am not sure what is called in r to do this?  Thank you again very much

Comment: @sxq2221 Look at my adapted answer